# Creating Queries From User Input & Known Fields

Tags: java, lucene

I'm trying to generate a query in Java to search a Lucene index.  The records in question have a recordState field so I'm starting my query with the following:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("recordState", "DRAFT")), Occur.MUST);
```

The trouble comes when I want to add a filter supplied by the user.  I had tried changing the code to:

```
String userQuery = ""; // This will be whatever the user types in
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, "", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29,
  new HashSet<String>()));
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("recordState", "DRAFT")), Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(queryParser.parse(userQuery), Occur.MUST);
```

If the user enters `record_id:123` as their query, the query I end up with will be `+recordState:DRAFT +record_id:123` - great. If the user enters `+record_id:123`, the final query is `+recordState:DRAFT +(+record_id:123)` - not ideal but it works.

But if a user enters `-record_id:123`, the final query is `+recordState:DRAFT +(-record_id:123)` which looks invalid & doesn't make much sense!

Is there a better way to combine the two query parts?  I can't append the user's query as plain text as if they don't start the character with +/-, the query would end up as `+recordState:DRAFT record_id:123` (record state = draft or record ID).

I'm thinking the only thing I can do is to test if the user query only contains one term & if so, remove any preceeding +/-.  But I would like to do this without any String manipulation & sticking to the Lucene API.

Comment: +recordState:DRAFT +(-record_id:123)

actually, it's ok it said - show me records, where first and second query matches, where first is term query and second is negate query - show everything except docs, matched by this termquery. so i dont see any issues with current approach

Comment: Although that's how I would read that syntax, it's not doing that. `+recordState:DRAFT +(-record_id:123)` & `+recordState:DRAFT -record_id:123` do not return the same result :(

Comment: yep, cause it's different query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you provide isn't so terribly wrong, actually, but may not turn out like you expect.

The query:

```
-record_id:123
```

Is not very useful.  Lucene does not support pure negative queries.  Lucene needs to have something to search for, if it is only given things *not* to match, it will match nothing.

Since your goal appears to be just filtering to only documents with `recordState` = `DRAFT`, having been given a valid query, it would be reasonable to return no results, since the user entered query isn't really any good.

A query like:

```
+recordState:DRAFT +(-record_id:123 anotherfield:terms)
```

would be just fine, and:

```
+recordState:DRAFT +(+record_id:123)
```

The `+` inside the parentheses isn't really necessary, but it will also work without any problems.

If you want to detect a pure negative query like this, either by analyzing the query string, or iterating a `BooleanQuery` return from the parser, something like:

```
BooleanQuery query = (BooleanQuery)parser.parse;
BooleanClause[] clauses = query.getClauses();
if (clauses.length == 1 && clauses[0].getOccur() == BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT) {
    booleanQuery.add(clauses[0]);
} else {
    booleanQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
}
```

Which might deal with the very specific case, but keep in mind, if the user can create a query of arbitrary complexity, they can just as well create the same issue nested somewhere in the query.  Also, the query parser is not guaranteed to return a `BooleanQuery`, so that's a bit of an assumption.

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion that I came to last night.  I didn't see that I could get the Occur from the supplied clauses via the parser, so that's better than the string checking I was thinking of doing.